# How to get onclick button to show text in input box

Tags: html, button, input, onclick

I was having this problem with a more complex chunk of code, so I started messing with a html "joke" with the movie The Seven, and realized it was the same problem. Why doesn't it do anything when I click the button? I've tried it adding a function and script as well, get same problem. I want it to show the text inside the (formerly blank) input box when you click the button.

```
<html>
<body>
The Box:<input type="text" id="thebox" value="" size=10>
<br><input type="button" value="What's in the booooox?" onclick="document.getElementById('thebox').innerHTML='head of gwyneth paltrow';">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: change `innerHTML` to `value`

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML`, as the name suggests, refers to the HTML content of an element. You need to use `value`

```
The Box:<input type="text" id="thebox" value="" size=10>
<br><input type="button" value="What's in the booooox?" onclick="document.getElementById('thebox').value='head of gwyneth paltrow';">
```

[See it in action](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zCJcp)